# Directional Derivative of Softmax

Tags: derivatives, neural-networks

I'm trying to solve an exercise about computing derivatives with softmax, but I'm somehow stuck.

I have a deep neural network $f(W,x)$, where $W$ are the weights, and I have a fixed weight-vector $\vec W = \nabla_W \frac 1 2 \| f(W,x_i)-y\|$. Note that here $x_i$ is a fixed point. Assuming that $\sigma$ is the softmax function, the final output of my network will be $\sigma(f(W,x))$.

I have to compute the norm of the following derivative:

$$\partial_{\vec W} (\sigma(f(W,x_i) - \sigma(f(W,x_i+r))$$

Where $r$ is a very small vector. Is there a formula which allows me to compute the following?

What I'm doing is the following, but I'm somehow stuck:

$\partial_{\vec W} (\sigma(f(W,x) - \sigma(f(W,x+r)) \approx \partial_{\vec W}(\langle \nabla_x \sigma(f(W,x),r\rangle) = \langle \vec W,\nabla_{\vec W}(\langle\nabla_x\sigma(f(w,x),r\rangle)\rangle =$

$\sum_i r_i \langle \nabla_{\vec W} \sigma
(f(W,x),\partial_{x_i}\nabla_{\vec W} \sigma (f(W,x) \rangle. \ \ \ $(1)

I thought about proceeding using Cauchy Schwarz both on the norm and on the expected value but I'm not sure on how to keep going,

How can I estimate the norm of (1)? 
Thank you, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: There's nothing special there (unless you want to use an approximation on the basis of $\| r \| \ll 1$), it's just the ordinary vector chain rule.

Comment: Yes, I have $\| r \|$ << 1 ! What would you suggest? I'm actually trying an approximation method, but it looks like I'm going nowhere

Comment: If you are trying to use an approximation based on $\| r \| \ll 1$ then you additionally want to differentiate with respect to $x$ so that the dependence on $x$ is linearized out.

Comment: What do you mean? $\partial_W \partial_x (\sigma(f(W,x) - \sigma(f(W,x+r))$ ?

Comment: I mean that $g(x+r)-g(x) \approx \nabla g(x) \cdot r$. In this case $g$ is $\partial_W \sigma(f(W,x))$.

Comment: Thanks! this leads to the case I've written in the EDIT, but from there on I still don't know what to do

Comment: Actually, my problem is that I don't know how to compute exactly $\partial_W(f(W,x))$, so adding one more derivative makes it more complicated for me

Comment: If you can't exactly differentiate then you want to go the other way entirely and do finite differences for both $W$ and $x$.

Comment: What do you mean by that? sorry to bother you but I'm not getting it